# Have 4 fields on a adf page. How to refresh their values from database one after the other based on use selection

Tags: jsf, oracle-adf, jdeveloper

I have an Oracle ADF page with 4 fields in the below order.

1. radio button (select one). Always populate the radio selection from values in database.
2. drop down list (select one): Empty by default. Pull the value from database based on radio button selection on 1.
3. drop down list (select one): Empty by default. Pull the values from database based on drop selection made on 2.
4. drop down list (select one): Empty by default. Pull the values from database based on drop selection made on 3.

I need to pass the values selected in 2, 3, 4 to a view/query in the model and retrieve a list and display it on a new page.

I have generated the entity and view objects in JDeveloper. How do I develop the above logic.

Any help on this is highly appreciated.

Comment: create dependant list of values . there r tons of tutorial out there for this .

Comment: Thanks Sam. I found this http://www.avioconsulting.com/blog/creating-cascading-dropdowns-adfbc-driven-adf-forms and couple of other examples.

Comment: You can update lists, pages based on events, listeners using backing bean in a JSF(Primefaces)-Spring-Hiberate app. Business services can be injected into these beans. I was wondering if we can do the same thing in a Oracle ADF app. In essence call business services in Model project of Oracle ADF fusion application. Is this a recommended approach in Oracle ADF world?

Comment: create a method in application module and expose it to view layer 
(beans,taskflow,pages) by adding it as a client interface.

Comment: Can you please eloborate or point a link or an example?